# Read Line-By-Line without using StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, text-files, streamreader, filereader

I have been doing A-Level Computing for a couple of months now and I have decided to make a phonebook relevant to the methods used in class. For my exam I am not allowed to use StreamReader etc... However, I can use methods such as FileOpen(1, "FILE NAME", OpenMode.Binary).

I want to store usernames and passwords in a text file (I know its not a good method but it links to my lessons). My .txt file is formatted like:
Username, Password.
Username2, Password2.

What would i be able to do to make it store each Username and Password in a list?

Here's what I've got... (don't know why it doesn't work)

```
Private Sub CheckAccount()
  Dim Username_File As New ArrayList
  Dim Username_Temp As String = ""
  Dim Password_File As New ArrayList
  Dim Password_Temp As String = ""

  FileOpen(1, "Users.txt", OpenMode.Binary)

  Do While Not EOF(1)
    Dim PosCount_Start As Integer = 0
    Dim PosCount_End As Integer = 0
    Dim TempChar As Char = ""

    Do
      FileGet(1, TempChar)
      If TempChar = "," Then Exit Do
      Username_Temp = Username_Temp + TempChar
      PosCount_End = PosCount_End + 1
    Loop

    Username_Temp = Username_Temp.Substring(PosCount_Start, (PosCount_End - PosCount_Start))
    Username_File.Add(Username_Temp)
    PosCount_End = 0
    Do
      FileGet(1, TempChar)
      If TempChar = "." Then Exit Do
      Password_Temp = Password_Temp + TempChar
      PosCount_End = PosCount_End + 1
    Loop

    Password_Temp = Password_Temp.Substring(0, PosCount_End)
    Password_Temp = Password_Temp.Trim
    Password_File.Add(Password_Temp)
    PosCount_End = 0
  Loop
  FileClose(1)

  For i = 0 To Username_File.Count - 1
    Dim Temp As String
    Temp = Username_File(i)

    If Temp.ToLower = Username.ToLower Then
      If Password = Password_File(i) Then
        LoggedIn = True
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a user class with properties... Also is this all together in the text, meaning each user isnt on their own line.

Comment: Are you allowed to read in the whole file at one with [File.ReadAllText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: What happens if someone puts a `,` comma or `.` period in their username/password?

Comment: Each user has one line in the .txt file "Username, Password.".  Also, users can't use commas or periods in their username/password. If they try to, it suggests they change it to a `_` .

Comment: I did originally use File.ReadAllText() but I was told to try using FileGet(#, "")